# Como traspasar de String a int con ceros adelante en una lectura de ficheros en java

Tags: java, string, formato, archivo, números-enteros

Estoy leyendo un archivo de text en Java linea por linea, contienes valores por ejemplo:

- 000036208
- 906275000
- 000700030

Utilizando FileReader y BufferedRead me devueleve un `String` con la linea correctamente,  pero al pasarla a `int` por el metodo `Integer.parseInt(Cadena);` pierdo los ceros en adelante y ademas, necesito que este numero pueda separarlo tipo:

- Caso 1: 0,0,0,0,3,6,2,0,8
  y estos valores ingresarlos en un arreglo de enteros

Bueno no necesario pasarlo a `int`, pero que pueda ingresar cada valor por separado a un arreglo

Answer (score 0):

```
String linea = "000036208";
int[] enteros = linea
        .chars() // obtener stream de caracteres
        .map(Character::getNumericValue) // convertir el caracter en entero
        .toArray() // crear el arreglo
        ;

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(enteros));
```